# SQL query about Nested query and NATURAL JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables.
First table is Activities and second is Members and last is Message.
Activities has a foreign key named Members_ID and primary key is Activity_ID.
Members' primary key is Members_ID.
Message recorded Activity_ID and Members_ID.
I wanna search about Activities NATURAL JOIN Members and I need a new column count for
Message's message_ID  where the Activity_ID is the same.

NATURAL JOIN:

```
SELECT*
    FROM Activities 
        NATURAL JOIN Members 
    WHERE Activities.Members_ID = Members.Members_ID;
```

COUNT(message_ID):

```
SELECT COUNT(message_ID) 
    FROM Message 
    WHERE Activity_ID = 123;
```

Question is:
How to search the above two things together?
I'd like have a table have Activities NATURAL JOIN Members with same Activities.Members_ID
and a virtual column which is COUNT(message_ID) from table Message.

Comment: I suggest avoiding natural joins; explicitly stating your join predicate is a better practice, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you wish to use a correlated subquery, like this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(message_ID) FROM Message WHERE Activity_ID = a.Activity_ID AND Members_ID = m.Members_ID) AS Message_Count
    FROM Activities AS a
        NATURAL JOIN Members AS m
    WHERE a.Members_ID = m.Members_ID;
```

But, I would avoid the natural join syntax:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(message_ID) FROM Message WHERE Activity_ID = a.Activity_ID AND Members_ID = m.Members_ID) AS Message_Count
    FROM Activities AS a
        JOIN Members AS m on a.Members_ID = m.Members_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks,but the(SELECT COUNT(message_ID) FROM Message WHERE Activity_ID = a.Activity_ID AND Members_ID = m.Members_ID
is not the right result what I need.
Because the different member may insert the to the same activity. The Message Table may has two record from different member but same activity_ID.

Comment: SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(message_ID) FROM Message WHERE Activity_ID = a.Activity_ID) AS Message_Count
    FROM Activities AS a
        JOIN Members AS m on a.Members_ID = m.Members_ID;

Comment: THe Right Answer.
Thanks for Tim Lehner and everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH MessageTallies 
     AS
     (
      SELECT Activity_ID, COUNT(message_ID) AS tally
        FROM Message
       GROUP 
          BY Activity_ID
     )
SELECT *
  FROM Activities 
       NATURAL JOIN Members 
       NATURAL JOIN MessageTallies
UNION CORRESPONDING
SELECT *, 0 AS tally
  FROM Activities 
       NATURAL JOIN Members 
 WHERE Activity_ID NOT IN (SELECT Activity_ID FROM MessageTallies):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Activity_ID, a.col1, a.col2, ..., a.colx, COUNT(mg.message_ID)
    FROM Activities a
        INNER JOIN Members m
            ON a.Members_ID = m.Members_ID
        INNER JOIN Message mg
            ON a.Activity_id = m.Activity_ID 
    GROUP BY a.Activity_ID, a.col1, a.col2, ..., a.colx;
```

Comment: I need the Activity_ID is FROM a join m. Activity_ID = 123 is just example.

Comment: @YuChunLin See my edited answer. Is that more like what you want?

Comment: Thanks Joe. But it looks not like what I want.

Comment: it will be a new table with Activities a NATURAL JOIN Members m AND nested query or something to add a new column COUNT(m.message_ID) from Message Table.

Comment: COUNT(m.message_ID) the m.message_ID is in Message Table Not in Members Table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @YuChunLin Added the second JOIN for messages